# What is the significance of proc/<pid>/fdinfo/0? who creates it?

Tags: linux-kernel

When I create a message queue, in a thread, a file descriptor is generated, under 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... at path `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo`
with values like 31, 32, 40, 41...

What is the significance of `/proc/<pid>fdinfo/0`? Who creates it?

What happens if it is overwritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel “creates” it, as part of the [`/proc` file system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). It contains information on file descriptor 0 (usually standard input) of the process whose pid matches the containing directory.

These files can’t be overwritten: they are read-only, in a read-only directory. Even `root` can’t write to them.

Comment: what should I understand  if  /proc/<pid>/fdinfo/0  is not present after I ran my program ? is it my program corrupted the fdinfo file ? or is it ok if  0 is not present ?

Comment: The file is only present as long as (a) the program is running and (b) it has file descriptor 0 open. If it closes file descriptor 0, `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/0` disappears; if it exits, `/proc/<pid>` in its entirety disappears.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot.  What do you consider as standard input  because my device do not have keyboard connected I mean i do not use stdin.  so i keep writing and reading messages on to message Queue while my program is still running, /proc/<pid>/fdinfo/0 value suddenly disappears.  I am wondering if eventfd.c  number of event counter got overflow or something like that.

Comment: All processes get a standard input, whether or not there’s a keyboard or anything like that. There might be something in the program’s error logs, it shouldn’t close fd 0 suddenly like that (you’d expect it to close it on startup if it doesn’t need it, but not afterwards). Beyond that I’m afraid I’m not going to be much help...